# Boot from an USB key

Tags: usb, ext4, ubuntu-gnome

I want to resize a mount EXT4 partition, but some article explains that I need to boot from an USB key to resize this partition. Could anyone explain to me what they mean exactly? How could I do that?

With df -h command:

[image]

Do I need to back-up the actual partition on an external hard drive to modify this partition? In fact, this partition contains Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a full drive encrypted install? If so that uses LVM and you have to use LVM tools to resize partitions. but with LVM you do not have to use live installer. Generally standard partitions have to be edited when not mounted. Often using gparted from Ubuntu live installer or gparted. But gparted does not work on LVM partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your install isn't encrypted (see [oldfred's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867594/boot-from-an-usb-key-help/867659#comment1342894_867594) if it is), then you'll need to create a bootable ubuntu live USB with these instructions:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Then you will need to restart your computer, and force it to boot off the USB (it may do so by default, otherwise there will be a key combination or BIOS option to do this, but it will depend on your specific computer so I'd suggest googling how to change where it boots from for your specific computer).

Once the USB is booted, you'll first need to connect it to the internet (the same way you normally would). Then you should open a terminal and install gparted using `sudo apt install gparted`.

You can then launch gparted by using `sudo gparted` from the terminal, and resize your partition from there.
It is recommended you take a backup of at least any important data on the partition before going ahead with the resize as data corruption is possible, especially if you are moving a partition and not just resizing it.

Comment: gparted is included in a Live Ubuntu install, just run it from Unity.